# $wpdb->get_var multiple queries in one database check

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I am using the $wpdb->get_var php code to get the first name and last name on the records, in the wp_usermeta table...
But because the field value is stored in the same cell, I don't know how to merge it into one string.  Right now I do it like this:

```
$_EmployeeFName = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name' and `user_id` = %d ", $_REQUEST['empid']));
$_EmployeeLName = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' and `user_id` = %d ", $_REQUEST['empid']));
```

Is there a way to do that in ONE pull from the database? I don't want to do this a lot, to save the database from so many pulls...

I don't know how to do it though.

do you?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do your own database queries? Use the WP functions to do it for you.

```
$empid = (int) $_REQUEST['empid'];
$name = get_user_meta($empid, 'first_name', true) . ' ' . get_user_meta($empid, 'last_name', true);
```

Comment: That did it! I did not know that would work. :) I did not see it anywhere. Thank you!!

Comment: Here is another question. In the form, I am putting a form tag and some hidden fields, then content.

Wordpress is taking those html fields and making them put line breaks in, so there is a huge space between content.
How can I remove the line breaks they cause so that they are not putting a lot of white blank lines on the form?

Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a single query that retrieves one field but for multiple results (e.g. to avoid round-trips to the database), the simplest explanation is to use `get_results()` instead.

Taking your query:

```
$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name' and `user_id` = %d ", $_REQUEST['empid']))
```

... and seeing how it is nearly identical to the one of the other field:

```
$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' and `user_id` = %d ", $_REQUEST['empid']))
```

... I would suggest rolling them together into a single query:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value`
        FROM `wp_usermeta`
        WHERE `meta_key` IN ('first_name', 'last_name')
            AND `user_id` = %d;", $_REQUEST['empid']));
```

Your `$results` object would be an array with `meta_key` and `meta_value` properties on each object.

You could then get your individual fields as follows:

```
foreach($results as $rec) {
    switch($rec->meta_key) {
        case "first_name":
            $_EmployeeFName = $rec->meta_value;
            break;
        case "last_name":
            $_EmployeeLName = $rec->meta_value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Using `get_results()` allows you not only to query for both at the same time, but also to be able to differentiate between the two (providing both the `meta_key` and the corresponding `meta_value`).

Comment: ah, I see! That is how to do it in a single query, that is what I was looking for! Thank you!!